# Adding field with migration on mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, migration

So I tried to migrate a new field to the mongoDB collections. 
New field is a array that is filled with objects.
The migration runs and is successful, it even shows the new field when 
looking the collections.
Problem comes when I try to add data to this field - it shows that the
field is undefined.
What should be done to overcome this problem?

Migration code:

```
exports.up = async function(db) {
await db
    .collection('useractions')
    .update({}, {
      $set: {
        history: []
      }
    }, {multi: true, upsert: false});
};
```

Code to populate the new field:

```
const bookId = req.body.bookId;
const timestamp = req.body.timestamp;
const userId = req.body.userId;
const container = {bookId, timestamp};
UserAction.update(
  { userId },
  {$set: { history: container}},
  (err, cb) => {
  if(err)next({error: err});
    res.status(200).json({
      cb
    })
  })
```

EDIT: 
Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userActionModel = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: String
  },
  likes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Podcast',
    default: []
  }],
  tags: {
    type: [String],
    default: []
  },
  orderedBook: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Show',
    default: []
  }]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('userAction', userActionModel);
```

Comment: Can you please add mongoose schema used?

Comment: added the schema